# In django-rest-framework, I want to output the childdb in the same parentdb by putting the parentdb name in the url parameter

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

There is a model that binds the user with a foreignkey. What I want to do is set the url parameter to
I'm writing an api that prints the items of children with the same parent when I put as_view/int:parentpk, but I can't implement it due to my lack of skills. Please help

Here is a model.py that accepts a user as a foreignkey

```
   class TestingTasks(models.Model): 
        Taskname = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)    
        dateofuse = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
        Compressing = models.TextField()    
        Path = models.FileField(null=True)    
        parent_id = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='users', on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
```

And here is views.py

```
class TestingAPI(APIView):
permission_classes = [AllowAny]

def get(self, request, company_id):
    instance = TestingTasks.objects.filter(parent_id=id)
    serializer_class = TestingSerializer(instance)
    return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

Here is urls.py

```
path("Testing/<int:company_id>",views.TestingAPI.as_view())
```

I need to implement a total of three get, put, and delete, but I can't do the rest because I can't get.
I'd appreciate it if you could give me a direction on how to do it. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the functions in class

```
class TestingAPI(APIView):
      permission_classes = [AllowAny]

      def get(self, request, company_id):
          instance = TestingTasks.objects.filter(parent_id=company_id)
          serializer_class = TestingSerializer(instance)
          return Response(serializer_class.data)

      def put(self, request, company_id):
          ...
      def delete(self, request, company_id):
          ...
```

Comment: I tried doing the same but I get this error.
TypeError at /api/Testing/27
Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.

Comment: I think because you pass 'id' in filter, you should pass 'company_id', I will edit answer also

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am getting this error, what should I do?
here is the error code:
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `Taskname` on serializer `TestingSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Taskname'.